# Android Add a picture to frame

Tags: android, image

[image]

Hello everyone i have a frame given below, I have to add user picture choosen from  gallery  or camera on white board given. I have many frames and in each frame location of whiteboard is changed.
Please help how can i do it. any library to use it??
If there is any tutorial given help me
Thanks in advance..

Comment: anyone have no idea??